# Accessing OpenCV 1.0 image pixel values and using them in FFTW

Tags: opencv, pixel, fftw

I am using an OpenCV 1.0 based calibration toolbox to which I am making small additions. My additions require the use of the FFTW library (OpenCV has DFT functions but they aren't to my liking).

I have been trying to access the pixel values of an image and store those pixel values into a FFTW_complex type variable. I have tried a lot of the different suggestions (including openCV documentation) but I have been unable to do this properly.

The code below doesn't bring up any inconsistencies with variable types during the build or whilst debugging; however, the pixel values obtained and stored in "testarray" are a repetition of the values [13, 240, 173, 186]. Does anyone know how to access the pixel values and store them into FFTW compliant matrices/containers?

```
    //.....................................//
    //For image manipulation
    IplImage* im1 = cvCreateImage(cvSize(400,400),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);      
    int width = im1 -> width;
    int height = im1 -> height;
    int step = im1 -> widthStep/sizeof(uchar);
    int fft_size = width *height;

    //Setup pointers to images
    uchar *im_data = (uchar *)im1->imageData;
    //......................................//

    fftw_complex testarray[subIM_size][subIM_size]; //size of complex FFTW array

    im1= cvLoadImage(FILEname,0);
    if (!im1)printf("Could not load image file");

    //Load imagedata into FFTW arrays
    for( i = 0 ; i < height ; i++ ) {
        for( j = 0 ; j < width ; j++) {
            testarray[i][j].re =  double (im_data[i * step + j]);
            testarray[i][j].im = 0.0;
        }
    }
```

---

I found out the problem. I had been using the wrong approach to access it.

This is what I used:

```
testarray[i][j].re = ((uchar*)(im1->imageData + i *im1->widthStep))[j]; //double (im_data[i * step + j]);
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I am using C++ in Visual Studio 2008 and this is the way is use:

If we have a loop like that for going through the image:

```
    for (int y = 0 ; y < height; y++){
        for (int x = 0 ; x < width ; x++){
```

Then, the access to the fftw variable ( let's call it A) will be done as follows:

```
   A [ height * y + x][0] = double (im_data[height * y + x]);
   A [ height * y + x][1] = 0;
```

Hope it helps!

Antonio